# FormMail.pl 1.93 Multiple URl contact Form

Tags: perl, url, formmail

I am using FormMail.pl version 1.93 for form submission. I have asked this question before for FormMail 3.14m1 but now I am using FormMail.pl version 1.93

I have a single contact-us form and what I would like to do is use this single form such as contactus.html (not multiple copies of this form) everywhere on my website as my site has different contact-us sections based on the department.

Let's say the contact-us form for marketing should email to technical@mydomain.com, contact-us form for sales should email to sales@mydomain.com, HR's contact-us form should email to hr@mydomain.com.

How can I use the single form while redirecting the submission to the appropriate department email address?

I am using FormMail.pl Version 1.93 for email submission

Comment: [No.](http://enwp.org/Matt's_Script_Archive)

Comment: You can't just say "I am using FormMail" and expect people to know what you mean. There are dozens of programs out there called FormMail - we need to know whose version of FormMail you are using. From the version numbers it looks like you were using the nms version, but now you've switched to the Matt's Script Archive version. That sounds like a step backwards to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FormMail 1.93 seems to be the version from [Matt's Script Archive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matt%27s_Script_Archive). The programs from that site are badly written, potentially buggy and (as you have, no doubt, discovered for yourself) unsupported. Even Matt Wright himself [no longer recommends](http://www.scriptarchive.com/nms.html) their use.

You would be better advised to use the versions from [the nms project](http://nms-cgi.sourceforge.net/). It sounds like you were using nms' version 3.14m1, but stopped for some reason. Why is that?

No matter which version you use, your problem is basically the same. In pretty much any version of FormMail the email recipient is either hard-coded in the program or derived from a form input (often a hidden form input) on the HTML page. If you're using the same installation of the program for different email addresses you can't hard-code the address within the program (for, hopefully, obvious reasons). So you're left with getting the address from the HTML page.

But you say you want to use the same form for different contact addresses. I'm not sure how you think this is going to work. How does the form know how it is being used? Are you perhaps embedding the form within various pages using iframes? I suppose it might be possible to change the value of the recipient form input depending on how the form is being accessed. You'd need to do this with Javascript.

The recommended way to approach this is to have a single copy of the FormMail program which is called from several different HTML forms.

Comment: I tried to use NMS FormMail 3.14m1 but this not working on my localhost it giving  "Premature end of script headers:" error and this error "Can't locate CGI/NMS/Script/FormMail.pm in @INC (@INC contains:" I search google but not be able to  find the solution.

Comment: Did you ask for support with your nms problem on the nms support mailing list? As described in the README file that comes with all of the the nms programs. If you look at the nms download page (http://nms-cgi.sourceforge.net/scripts.shtml) it says the 3.14m1 is for expert users. There's a 3.14c1 version that most people should be using instead. For the 'm' version you need to install the individual modules that make up the program. The 'c' version has all of the modules bundled into the program (and is therefore easier to install).

Comment: thanks a lot dave. i downlaod the  recommended 3.14c1 file. its working.

Comment: thanks a lot Dave. I downloaded the recommended 3.14c1 file. its working. Now my question is how can I  use single html form for all differnt departments and send to a recipient based on the  department email links. let say I have a home page which have 3 email addresses links (sales@mydomain.com, hr@mydomain.com, tech@mydomain.com) clicking on each links should go to contactus.html (only have one contactus.html) page but based on email link clicked my conact us form should be send to  that specific recipient.

Comment: such as If i click sales and fill the form then it should send to sales, if clicked the link hr@@mydomain.com then form must be send to Hr@mydomain.com.

Comment: I guess you would need to write Javascript which changes the value of the recipient field based on the referrer.